# Passing properties from ts component to be used in SASS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass

I'm trying to pass some properties (height and width) to the Icon component (that can only take 3 properties className path and viewBox) so I can not use inline style to add the width and height.
Is there a way to pass those height and width properties to be used in Sass ?
here is the component:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { Icon } from '@kame/ui';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import styles from './creation-button.module.scss';

type Props = {
  icon: {
    path: string;
    viewBox: string;
    height: 20px
    width: 20px
  };
  title: string;
  onClick: () => void;
  key: string;
};

function CreationButton(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.onClick} type="button" className={styles['button']}>
      <div className={styles['button__icon-container']}>
        <Icon
          className={styles['button__icon']}
          path={props.icon.path}
          viewBox={props.icon.viewBox}
        />
      </div>
      <span className={styles['button__title']}>{props.title}</span>
    </button>
  );
}

export default memo(CreationButton);
```

Comment: Never heard of this `@kame/ui` you're importing it from. Couldn't find any docs for it as well? Otherwise, it might be possible to wrap it in a `styled-component`, allowing to add props arbitrarily. You'd `const StyledIcon = styled(Icon)`height:20px` ` for instance.

Comment: oh, its companies module, and i can not change the Icon inside it, is there anyway to do it with className or this classNames library to have multiple classNames because im using sass ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you set width and height to `styles['button__icon']` isn't affect the icon size?

Comment: No, I get the width and height as a property, it can 20px or more. and i want to pass those values and use them inside sass